# Issue with SimpleScreenRecorder

Tags: screencast, desktop-recording

I'm trying to start recording using SimpleScreenRecorder.

The setup for this recording is as below:

[image: picture_1]

[image: picture_2]

And the error I'm getting is:

```
[PageRecord::StartPage] Starting page ...
[JACKInput::Init] Error: Could not connect to JACK!
[PageRecord::StartPage] Error: Something went wrong during initialization.
[PageRecord::StartPage] Started page.
[PageRecord::StartOutput] Starting output ...
[Muxer::Init] Using format webm (WebM).
[Muxer::AddStream] Using codec libx264 (libx264 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10).
[VideoEncoder::PrepareStream] Using pixel format nv12.
[BaseEncoder::EncoderThread] Encoder thread started.
[Muxer::AddStream] Using codec libvorbis (libvorbis).
[AudioEncoder::PrepareStream] Using sample format f32p.
[BaseEncoder::EncoderThread] Encoder thread started.
[Muxer::Start] Error: Can't write header!
[BaseEncoder::~BaseEncoder] Stopping encoder thread ...
[BaseEncoder::EncoderThread] Encoder thread stopped.
[BaseEncoder::~BaseEncoder] Stopping encoder thread ...
[BaseEncoder::EncoderThread] Encoder thread stopped.
[PageRecord::StartOutput] Error: Something went wrong during initialization.
```

Comment: Did you intend to use JACK as the audio back-end? Ubuntu's default is PulseAudio. For applications that don't support PulseAudio there's a fall-back ALSA device that sends its audio data to PulseAudio.

Comment: no answer to this question, but maybe helpful. I use `Kazam` for screen recording and I'm very happy with it.

Answer (score 2):

I have this problem in Ubuntu live USB version and used mp3 as audio codec instead of **Vorbis** like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just to note, I did not have speaker only option in Source drop down:

[image]

These settings worked for me:
[image]

(Keeping frame rate low might lead to small file size.)

So with above, we are asking to record both microphone and system internal audio. But, I wanted only system internal audio. So I reduced microphone audio to zero from ubuntu settings.

[image]

Next simplescreenrecorder screen:

[image]

With these settings I was able to record screen with system audio.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK WebM *container* being an alternative to commercial Formats such as *h264* or MPEG4, AFAIK may not be used with the later format (see the warning in your screenshot).